# Iterating Hair Particle Settings in Python code help!

Tags: python, particles, hair

I'm working on grooming an animal character and want to keep my over all groom while being able to duplicate it to adjust different settings, keeping each iteration in tact and separate from its original. Blender currently wont allow iterations of a Particle System's Particle Settings if you have made adjustments in the Particle Editor.

So I found a call operator code some one released on Blender Artists (https://blenderartists.org/t/duplicate-edited-hair-particles/1247900) that allows you to iterate a Particle System and it's Particle Settings after you have already made adjustments in the Particle Editor. The only problem is it does it for every Particle System in the entire index, and not just the selected one. Is there any way to add to this code to allow the iteration of only the selected Particle System?

Also, I'm using 2.93 beta. Don't know if that helps.
Thank you in advance!

````
import bpy

class DuplicateGroomedParticles(bpy.types.Operator): 
    """Duplicates Particle System With New Settings"""
    bl_idname = "particle.duplicate_groomed"
    bl_label = "Duplicate Groomed Paricle System"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
         object = bpy.context.object
         object.active_index
         bpy.ops.particle.duplicate_particle_system(use_duplicate_settings=True)
         return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DuplicateGroomedParticles)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DuplicateGroomedParticles)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: So, I found out that if you hit F9 after duplicating your particle system you can tick a box that also allows you to iterate your particle settings after they have been adjusted by the particle editor. However, the first time you do it, it still iterates for the stack, after which it does it for only the selected ones.

But, I'm still curious how I would write that into the code I found.